# Register react hook form input filed with a dot in name

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I have a weird scenario where I need to register my input field with a name which has a dot in it.

(Actual usecase looks something like this **name={`members.${member.username}.${i}.endTime`}** where username can be mail id in some cases)

Example code:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (values) => {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <input {...register("test1")} />
      <br />
      <input {...register("test2")} />
      <br />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
);
```

}

Expected output - **{"test1":"test1","test2":"test2"}**

Is there any way I can use the form like this

```
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
      <input {...register("test1")} />
      <br />
      <input {...register("test2.com")} />
      <br />
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And get the output as **{"test1":"test1","test2.com":"test2"}** instead of the expected output **{"test1":"test1","test2":{"com":"test2"}}**

Answer (score 2):

IF you use dot(.) notation in the name then you will always get the output like that

```
{"test1":"test1","test2":{"com":"test2"}}
```

My suggestion is why not use underscore(_) notation

```
name={members_${member.username}_${i}_endTime}
```

And If you really need dot(.) notation then inside `onSubmit ()` function you can replace those underscore(_) with dot(.)

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log(values);
    const finalOutput = Object.keys(values)
      .map((key) => {
        let name = key.replace("_", ".");
        return { [name]: values[key] };
      })
      .reduce((prev, cur) => {
        prev[Object.keys(cur)[0]] = Object.values(cur)[0];
        return prev;
      }, {});

    console.log(finalOutput);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
        <input {...register("test1")} />
        <br />
        <input {...register("test2_com")} />
        <br />
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```